ERROR : Sequelize model foreign keys not defined correctly
I have 2 table schemas Customer and Cart
Customer.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Customer = sequelize.define("custom", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        address: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        date: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    });

    Customer.associate = (models) => {
        Customer.hasOne(models.cart, { foreignKey: 'customerId' });
    };

    return Customer;
};

Cart.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Cart = sequelize.define("cart", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        customerId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'custom',
                key: 'id'
            }
        }

    }, {
        timestamps: false
    });

    Cart.associate = (models) => {
        // Define associations here
        Cart.belongsTo(models.customer, { foreignKey: 'customerId' });
    };

    return Cart;
};

I have index.js file for each models
customer/index.js
const dbConfig = require("../../config/db.config.js");

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
    host: dbConfig.HOST,
    dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
    operatorsAliases: false,

    pool: {
        max: dbConfig.pool.max,
        min: dbConfig.pool.min,
        acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
        idle: dbConfig.pool.idle
    }
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.customer = require("./customer.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.cart = require("../cart/cart.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.customer.associate(db);
module.exports = db;

cart/index.js
const dbConfig = require("../../config/db.config.js");

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
    host: dbConfig.HOST,
    dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
    operatorsAliases: false,

    pool: {
        max: dbConfig.pool.max,
        min: dbConfig.pool.min,
        acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
        idle: dbConfig.pool.idle
    }
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.cart = require('./cart.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.customer = require('../customer/customer.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.customer.associate(db);
module.exports = db;

and my server.js or the main file I am running
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const session = require('express-session');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Generate a random secret key
const secretKey = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');

app.use(session({
    secret: secretKey,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

const db_customer = require("./app/database/models/customer/index.js");
// const db_product = require("./app/database/models/product/index.js");

// db.sequelize.sync();
db_customer.sync();
const PORT = 4000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});

after running node server.js
i am getting this error
at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5) {
code: 'ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE',
errno: 1005,
sqlState: 'HY000',
sqlMessage: 'Can't create table s3941488_fsd_a2.carts (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")',
sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS carts (id INTEGER auto_increment , customerId INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), FOREIGN KEY (customerId) REFERENCES custom (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;',
parameters: undefined
},
sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS carts (id INTEGER auto_increment , customerId INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), FOREIGN KEY (customerId) REFERENCES custom (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;',
parameters: {}
}
It fixed the issue when I removed the references attribute from customerId attribute in the cart model schema, but I require for data integrity. I am not sure what causes the problem

What is the order of definition of your models? If the Cart model gets defined before the Customer model, it could result in this error

you mean the .sync() ones? or in the index files

I mean the order of when the .defines happen, which is controlled by the order of importing those models

It is because you import the models in the wrong order. The cart is getting defined before customer, so obviously it has no idea about custom.id.
db.cart = require('./cart.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.customer = require('../customer/customer.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);

You should load the customer first.
db.customer = require('../customer/customer.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.cart = require('./cart.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);

